# Cassandra slow DDL query since driver 3.0

Tags: java, cassandra

Since the java driver 3.0 i seen my ddl(data definition language) query take 1s each. Before all my queries used to take approximately 2s for all of them.

my ddl contain mostly CREATE TABLE but also DROP and CREATE KEYSPACE, CREATE TYPE and INDEXES.

They all take approximately the same time.

There is something that changed with the driver or with default setting?
Some one else has encounter this kind of problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are maybe hitting [JAVA-1120](https://datastax-oss.atlassian.net/browse/JAVA-1120). A fix for it should be released soon.

In the meanwhile, try to disable event debouncing:

```
Cluster cluster = Cluster.builder()
    .addContactPoints(...)
    // other options...
    .withQueryOptions(
        new QueryOptions()
            .setRefreshNodeIntervalMillis(0)
            .setRefreshNodeListIntervalMillis(0)
            .setRefreshSchemaIntervalMillis(0)
    ).build();
```

Comment: Yes, but I heard debouncing occurs when it's another driver that created the schema. It's not my case. I work around by not deleting Key space each time in my test, but by use TRUNCATE and IF EXIST. It's a work around but event with driver 2.1 I divided my all test time by factor two.

Comment: No, debouncing also happens for the client that alters the schema. That's precisely the purpose of JAVA-1120. By turning it off, you should achieve a sensible performance gain, although if you can avoid DDL statements in the first place, that's probably an even better solution.